# How to set up Django permissions for a custom user?

Tags: python, django, permissions

Good evening!

I have the following, a table containing my custom users (our dear Fellows) which will serve to login our users (by using the custom model).

[image]

**◢ The custom backends with it's custom user model for the Fellows table.**

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import CustomUser

class FellowBackend:
    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        '''Authenticates the user (custom model).'''
        # Parameters
        user_id = kwargs['username']
        password = kwargs['password']
        # Tentatives.
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(id = user_id)
            # If the password matches.
            if check_password(password, user.password):
                return user
            else:
                # Triggers default login failed.
                return None
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        '''TODO: Test if this override is required.'''
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(pk = user_id)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**◢ The custom user model.**

```
class Faction(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=64)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Faction'
            
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # ID.
    display_name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=64, db_collation='utf8mb4_general_ci')
    password = models.CharField(db_column='User_Password', max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    gold = models.IntegerField(db_column='Gold')  # Credits.
    faction = models.ForeignKey('Faction', models.RESTRICT, db_column='Faction', default=1)  # ID Faction.
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Last_Login', blank=True, null=True) # Last Login.

    # Admin Panel Abstract Fields
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'id'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = [] # id (username) and password required by default.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Fellows'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_name # Test.

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        """Is the user a member of staff?"""
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        """Is the user active?"""
        return self.active
```

So far so good, I can connect, do my stuff and even access the admin panel to manage every registered models if I am part of the staff.

However, let us say I want to add permissions between members of the staff, someone I hire for example to manage exclusively the Items table (from app Armory) while the other admin can have a total access to the models from any app.

**◢ The armory app will contain the Item model (and it's references).**

```
class Rarity(models.Model):
    ...
class ItemType(models.Model):
    ...

class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Identifier
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=64)  # Name of the item.
    description = models.TextField(db_column='Description', max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)  # Description of the item.
    source = models.CharField(db_column='Source', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)  # Source icon of the item.
    rarity = models.ForeignKey('Rarity', models.CASCADE, db_column='Rarity')  # ID of the rarity.
    item_type = models.ForeignKey('ItemType', models.CASCADE, db_column='Item_Type')  # ID of the item type.
    item_value = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column='Item_Value')  # Value of the item.
    sell = models.BooleanField(db_column='Sell')  # If the item can be sold.
    gift = models.BooleanField(db_column='Gift')  # If the item can be sent.
    dismantle = models.BooleanField(db_column='Dismantle')  # If the item can be dismantled.
    world = models.BooleanField(db_column='World')  # If the item can be found in the world (using the bot's !wheel command).

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'n_rpg_items'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**◢ And an articles app that will contain the Article model.**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # ID
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, db_column="ID_User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # User ID
    title = models.CharField(db_column='Title', max_length=32)  # Title
    content = models.TextField(db_column='Content')  # Content
    posted = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Posted')  # Date Posted
    source = models.CharField(db_column='Source', max_length=64, blank=True, null=True) # Source picture url of the article.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Articles'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Article : ' + self.title
```

To be more precise, when logging in the admin panel, **admin_a will only be able to manage Items**, while **admin_b will be able to manage everything**, Items and Articles.

The problem is, I searched for a while, the doc didn't helped me and I can't find anything that satisfies what I want to achieve so I am probably doing this wrong...

I was thinking about doing my own admin backends by adding a Role in the Fellows table but soon there will be no more use of framework if I start reinventing the wheel... :(

If anybody could share with me which solutions are conceivable, even a start, I would greatly appreciate!